# Get index of row in AngularJS light-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-light-grid

How can I access the index of each row in light-grid.

My code is here:

```
<tr lg-row-start>
    <td>
        <lg-view>
            {{ row.data.id }}<br />
            <input ng-click="selectRow(row.data, row.index)" name="lg-grid-select-row[]" value="{{row.data.id}}"
                 id="lg-grid-select-row{{row.data.id}}" class="lg-grid-select-row" type="checkbox" />
        </lg-view>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My light grid version is `0.3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `light-grid.js` like this:

```
scope.row = {
    index: scope.$index, // I added this line
    data: scope.$$rowData,
    view: gridController.getInitialView() || DEFAULT_VIEW,
    viewModel: angular.copy(scope.$$rowData),
    controller: rowController
};
```